# Using VueJS in Dreamweaver CC causes linter error when using strict mode

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, dreamweaver

I am using VueJS for front-end development and writing the code in **Dreamweaver CC 2017 (build 9314)**. DW's built-in linter is giving me the following error when using JavaScript in 'strict mode':

```
'Vue' is not defined.
```

I have the JS code in a typical *app.js* file and the view/HTML in *index.html* and I get the above error. However, when I put the JS code in the same index.html file, the error disappears.

Is there anything I can do to work on two files and not get the error?

Thanks.

Is there a way to hide or fix that error in Dreamweaver CC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Dreamweaver [uses](https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/linting-code.html) `JSHint` for it's linter. And allows you to specify a configuration file named `DW.jshintrc` by which you could add `Vue` to your globals list:

http://jshint.com/docs/options/#globals

```
{
    "globals": { "Vue": true }
}
```

Also I believe you can use a inline JSHint rule like so:

```
/* globals Vue */
```

Which will let the linter know that `Vue` is a global variable not defined in the current block of code.